# Unexpected Colon in SWFUpload Settings

Tags: javascript, swfupload

Chrome is telling me that it isn't expecting a colon in my SWFUpload settings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var swfu;
    var settings = function() {
        flash_url: 'swfupload.swf',
        upload_url: 'uploadtest.php', //this is the line
        file_post_name: 'file',
        file_size_limit: '10 MB',

        button_image_url: 'styles/images/browse2.png',
        button_width: 232,
        button_height: 84,
        button_placeholder_id: 'swfbutton'
    };
    swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);
});
```

Screenshot: http://imgdiode.com/BI2QNY

Usually I see syntax errors like this when a previous item is missing or something similar, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
var settings = { ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5LLQ/